# In module tf_pose not import TfPoseEstimator library

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can't execute this code:

```py
from tf_pose.estimator import TfPoseEstimator
```

```
Error-
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tf_pose/pafprocess/pafprocess.py in swig_import_helper()
     16         try:
---> 17             return importlib.import_module(mname)
     18         except ImportError:
```

Comment: welcome. please review [ask] and [mre]. your question is currently unanswerable because it lacks vital context.

Comment: Did you install that module? Or, is it a module that you created?

Comment: Does [this](https://medium.com/@gsethi2409/pose-estimation-with-tensorflow-2-0-a51162c095ba) reference answer your question? Thanks!